# need help getting values from a click function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, click

So I have a problem getting the ID's from my buttons. My code is only returning the id value from the first tic button and not the rest of them when I click on them.

here is the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary tic" id="0">#</a>
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary tic" id="1">#</a>
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary tic" id="2">#</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the javascript:

```
const tick = document.querySelector('.tic');

tick.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    var slot = tick.id;
    console.log(slot);
});
```

it only returns 0 when I click on the first button but it does not return 1 when I click on the second one. Instead, it doesnt do anything. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: `document.querySelector('.tic')` only returns the first element with that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the first element.

Instead, use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all elements, loop through each and add a `click` event listener:

```js
const tick = document.querySelectorAll('.tic');

tick.forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var slot = e.id;
    console.log(slot);
  });
})
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary tic" id="0">#</a>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary tic" id="1">#</a>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary tic" id="2">#</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, even better, use event delegation:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("tic")) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary tic" id="0">#</a>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary tic" id="1">#</a>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary tic" id="2">#</a>
  </div>
</div>
```